# iptables/haproxy limit packets per second

Tags: iptables, tcp, bandwidth, haproxy, packets

Is it possible to limit incoming tcp packets per second (or bytes per second) with iptables or haproxy? I have found many examples but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip,srcport --hashlimit-name HASHNAME --hashlimit-htable-max 5000 --hashlimit-htable-expire 10000 --hashlimit-above 5/sec -j DROP`